# Convert xs:Enumerations in XSD to dropdown lists in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I have an XSD file which contains the schema for my XML. The XSD file contains an `xs:Enumeration` definition, which allows me to choose between 5 options as a value for one of the nodes.

Now, we want to be able to generate this data through Excel, so that non-technical people can create it.

When I import this XSD file into Excel, i want the `xs:enumeration` values to be listed as dropdowns.

How do I get to do that?

**Edit:** Starting a bounty. To win, I need a working sample code for this :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As xcut says, there is no easy way to do this. But it can be done. What you'll need to do is:

1. Use the `WorkbookAfterXmlImport`
   event to read your schema with MSXML
   for your enums.
2. Find the mapped column in your data
   table for the element that has your
   enums in code. This is usually a `ListObject`.
3. Add these enums to a list in
   `Validation.InCellDropdown` to your
   mapped column range, minus the
   heading.

Answer (score 3):

I eye-balled this question a few times yesterday, and didn't answer it, partly because there is no quick solution to what you're trying to do.

You are a bit unclear on what exactly you're trying to achieve: exporting enums from Excel as a Schema, or importing enums from a Schema into Excel, or round-trip.

If you are willing to maintain your spreadsheet as a "master" copy then you can do the following:

- Main the enums in Excel (e.g. Column A has a type name and the rows in Column B have the values)
- Periodically, when you need to, hit "Save as..." XML Spreadsheet
- Run XSLT on the XML spreadsheet to produce the schema file

Well, it's an idea, at least :) Alternatively, you can write VBA code into it.

Comment: I am trying to export an XML schema to Excel. To put it in your words, XML Schema is the master copy.

In my Master XML Schema, I have an XSD enumeration... When i add that enumeration as an XML map, the cell should be a dropdown with all the enumerations listed

Comment: You can still do this in XSLT, if you are willing to experiment. Set up a spreadsheet with a drop-down box; save the spreadsheet as XML (XML Spreadsheet). Open that in an editor. Then create a stylesheet that transforms the schema to something that looks like the saved file.